# What's the difference between multicollinearity and autocorrelation?

Tags: multiple-regression, autocorrelation, multicollinearity

I am learning about MLR and I don't quite understand the difference between these two terms? Could someone explain it to me?
Additionally, if I made a model and I wanna validate the conditions necessary for it to be a good model, should I test both conditions (multicollinearity and autocorrelation)? or only one of those.
I believe this might be a very basic question, I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Multicollinearity** is high correlation between two or more independent regressors.

For example, in a regression:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + e_i$$

multicollinearity would be present if $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ would be highly correlated together. In fact one way how to detect multicollinearity is to run auxiliary regression between the above two independent variables:

$$x_{1i} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_{2i} + \epsilon_i$$

collect the $R^2$ and calculate variance inflation factor $VIF= \frac{1}{1-R^2}.$ Higher values of VIF indicate higher multicollinearity with values above 5 respectively 10 (different textbooks will offer slightly different rule of thumb) would indicate problematic multicollinearity.

Multicollinearity, itself does not lead to biased results but it inflates variance of standard errors so you would want to avoid it if possible.

**Autocorrelation** might refer either to autocorrelation in errors, or also more generally to time series models where variables are related to their past realizations. From your question I assume that you want to know about the former rather than latter.

When it comes to autocorrelation in error term then it means that different errors are correlated with each other (usually across time but spatial autocorrelation can sometiems exists as well). A simple example of autocorrelation would be some simple time series model such as:

$$y_t = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_t +\varepsilon_t$$

where $\varepsilon_t$ would be given by:

$$\varepsilon_t = \rho \varepsilon_{t-1} +v_t$$

with $\rho \neq 0$. The above essentially means that errors today will be correlated with errors yesterday.

Autocorrelation in itself does not bias the coefficient of the model of interest, but it does bias the estimation of standard error so without detecting and correcting for autocorrelation you would not be able to make correct inference (i.e. $t$-statistics and $p$-values will be wrong even if $\gamma$ will be correct).

There are various tests for autocorrelation. For example, Durbin-Watson test for first order autocorrelation or Breusch-Godfrey test for higher order autocorrelation to name just two. You can read more about these tests in Verbeek (2008), A Guide to Modern Econometrics 4th ed. pp 116.

Comment: You should mention multicollinearity can occur between more than two regressors as well.

Comment: @RichardHardy you are right I edited it

Comment: @1muflon1, The part "multicollinearity would be present if $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ would be highly correlated together" is false if $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ are vectors. Could you clarify if they are vectors or respective coordinates of a pair of vectors? If they're coordinates then how do you estimate their correlation? For example, consider two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -0.5 & 0\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$. They are perfectly correlated but far from collinear.

Comment: @mathgeek they are just variables not vectors

Comment: @1muflon1, but multicollinearity is about vectors, not variables. You just represent a variable as a vector when you talk about multicollinearity of variables (features). Anyway it's just false that high correlation implies collinearity (see my example above). So, how should one understand your quote "Multicollinearity is high correlation between two or more independent regressors"?

Comment: @mathgeek 1. Sorry, I thought that you think x is a vector of variables. 2. Multicolonearity is a linear association between two independent regressors. For example a perfect multicolinearity would occur if two regressors would have perfectly linear relationship like x_1=x_2+10 for example. The correlation coefficient in a linear model tells you how close relationship is to perfect linear relationship R^2 of 1 implies perfect linear relationship which means perfect multicolinearity. High correlation  between two regressors (close to 1) imply the model suffers from multicolinearity. Also

Comment: Also in the example of the two vectors you show there would be perfect multicolinearity in your model. If you need to see it in your own eyes just regress some another random variable on the two variables represented by those two vectors you made on in Stata or R or Python and you will see one of the variables will drop out due to perfect multicolinearity

Comment: @1muflon1, Check it. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 2 & -0.5 \\ 3 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$. In this case $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.83 \\ 1.33\end{bmatrix}$. Nothing is dropped. For you to visualise I made [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFBeu.png) plot, where red vectors are column vectors of the given matrix (they are not collinear), and the orange one is the target vector. By looking at the dotted vector you can see where the projection is. You still think you're going to lose one of the variables?

Comment: @1muflon1, Btw, it's apparent from the plot these two vectors are NOT collinear. Though it may be not that obvious to see they're perfectly correlated.

Comment: @mathgeek no you check it, we are talking about regression analysis so you need at least 3 variables and where are the coefficients? Your calculations are completely off topic. You are not setting up a regression but a system of equations what you should do is to set up a regression model of following form $y= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 +e$ where $y=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$, $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$ and $x_2=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -0.5 & 0\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm{T}$

Comment: next either solve the model by hand by minimizing the sum of squares or use program of your choice, for example let's use `R`, here are the commands first set the variables: `x1<-c(1, 2, 3)`, `x2<-c(-1,-0.5,0)`, `y<-c(1,2,2)`. Next run the regression model using `test1<- lm(y~x1+ x2)` then enter `test1` to view the output and you will get the following: `Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
     0.6667       0.5000           NA` <- you can see that the coefficient for x2 could not be calculated and variable was dropped from the regression model

Comment: R does not explain what has happened, in programs such as stata which hold your hand with their UI  you would get warning message that it is due to multicolinearity, but you can have a look at literally any econometrics textbook you want, and you can read there that this is due to multicolinearity which causes singularity in calculation of variance

Comment: Lastly, here is a quote for you: Wooldridge (**one of the most cited econometricians**) Introduction to Econometrics pp 83: **"High (but not perfect) correlation between two or more independent variables is called multicollinearity"**  Also the brackets but not perfect refer to the fact that when correlation is perfect we call it perfect multicolinearity.... so here you have it, black on white - high correlation between two regressors implies multicolinearity

Comment: @1muflon1, Now I think you must be right, but I am confused. Isn't multicollinearity imply that vectors must be collinear? Because in my example they are not collinear and we still call this multicollinearity.

Comment: @mathgeek as mentioned previously here multicolinearity refers to a case where there is linear relationship between 2 independent variables. In this case $x_1$ can be shown to be given by a linear function of $x_2$.

Comment: @1muflon1, wait, but this exactly means that they must be collinear (at least in our case). You said: "$x_1$ can be shown to be given by a linear function of $x_2$", i.e. $x_1 = ax_2$. But this means these vectors are collinear. And that is not true in our case. How is it to be explained?

Comment: @mathgeek but they do not need to be proportional a linear function has this form $x_1=a+bx_2$ also this is perfect multicolinearity for just multicolinearity there can actually further be an error so that $x_1= a +bx_2 +e$ in your case you can easily calculate using simple algebra that $x_1 =2x_2+3$ hence there is a perfect linear relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: @1muflon1, You're right. I finally got where my mistake was. I thought that multicollinearity means that vectors are collinear, but that's wrong, right?

Comment: And since both perfect correlation and multicollinearity mean linear relationship, then they're just the same.

Comment: @mathgeek pretty much

Comment: @1muflon1, You said pretty much because I was wrong somewhere?

Comment: @mathgeek no because comments need to have minimum amount of words

Answer (score 0):

Autocorrelation is used for signals or time series. Autocorrelation is the correlation of the signal with a delayed copy of itself.

Multicollinearity, which should be checked during MLR, is a phenomenon in which at least two independent variables are linearly correlated (one can be predicted from the other).

Comment: You should mention multicollinearity can occur between more than two regressors as well.